# Trying to create a type body in PL/SQL, but keep getting errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a type body for my type `components_t`. Here's the code for that type:

```
create type components_t under product_t (compPrice number(5,2), 
compDesc varchar(15), compYear number(4),
member function changeDesc return varchar);
/
```

And here's the code I currently have for the type body:

```
create type body components_t as member function changeDesc
return varchar
is
begin
if self.compYear < 2005 then
return self.compDesc||' Discontinued';
end if;
end;
/
```

What I'm trying to do with the type body is if the year of the component is smaller than 2005, then concatenate `' Discontinued'` to the end of the description. I've tried entering this and get this error:

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for TYPE BODY COMPONENTS_T:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
     one of the following:
     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
     member constructor map
```

First off, I want to know if this is even possible in PL/SQL. Secondly, does anyone know what I can do to get the syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of formatting I had made your code more readable, and now you can understand what you missed.

The body can have n number of functions and procedures. Each have a `BEGIN-END`.. And finally, the `BODY` itself need a `END`.

Then for your first question, you can use a [CONSTRUCTOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i16312) function here.

```
create type components_t under product_t 
(
  compPrice number(5,2), 
  compDesc varchar(15),
  compYear number(4),
  constructor function changeDesc return self as result
);

/
create type body components_t as 
    /* First function */
    construction function changeDesc(compPrice number, compDesc varchar,compYear )
      return self as result
    is
    begin
       self.compYear := compYear;
       self.compDesc := compDesc;

       if self.compYear < 2005 then
         self.compDesc := self.compDesc||' Discontinued';
       end if;
       return; /* it has to return by default*/
    end changeDesc; /* your member function ends here */

    /* Next function or procedure */

end; /* the type declaration ends here */
/
```